# redirect to #location on the same page

Tags: node.js, express

I am using Express framework. I would like to redirect to the particular location on the same page after submitting my post request which is a connection to MySQL . Is there a way to do it. I was not able to find one... Thanks in advance!

Everything is work except it does not redirect to the location (queryTable) that I want. It always goes back to the top of the webpage.

Part of the code looks like the following (in app.js):

```
app.post("/showActivity", function(req, res){
    var query_params = [req.body.name];
    console.log("params = "+req.body.category);
    var q = 'SELECT name, activity_type, food_type, description, DATE_FORMAT(activity_time, "%M %D %Y") AS date FROM activities WHERE name="'+query_params[0]+'" ORDER BY activity_time DESC';
    console.log(q);
    connection.query(q, function(err, results){
        if (err) throw err;
        activityData = results;
        clickedAct = true;
        console.log(activityData);
        res.redirect("/#queryTable");
    });
});
```

Comment: is this being called via an ajax request?

Comment: var app = express(), i am not using ajax i think. i do hope there is an easy fix to my question without using other libraries, thanks!

Comment: In other words, how is this route being accessed by the browser?

Comment: it is a post request to the server, giving params to search in mysql database, keeping record of results in a server variable, then redirect to the same page, where another app.get("/") takes care of the rendering.

Comment: Ok, so, you're on a web page. What do you do on that webpage that initiates the post request to /showActivity? is it a form submit that initiates a postback to the server? Is it a form submit that triggers a javascript event that sends an XHR post request to the server? something else?

Comment: i am sorry I am newb! it is submitting a form

Comment: Is the form on the index page of your site? If not, what page?

Comment: @Adam yes my webpage is only one page. i just want to be able to redirect to particular location on the same page after submit a post request.